# LibGDX game crash after migrating to Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx

After migrating to Android Studio 3.4, the game now crashed. It works fine on 3.3. What does this mean?

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
    at 

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'
...

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/limtc/AndroidStudioProjects/Space War/android/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk_resources/debug/instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug/out/slice_1/resources_ap
,,,

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/limtc/AndroidStudioProjects/Space War/android/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk_resources/debug/instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug/out/slice_1/resources_ap
...

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/limtc/AndroidStudioProjects/Space War/android/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk_resources/debug/instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug/out/slice_1/resources_ap
...
```

After switching off instant run, I can now deploy to phone! But trying to generate bundle I now have:

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
...

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android:lintVitalRelease'
...

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':android:lintClassPath'.
...

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactResolveException: Could not download groovy-all.jar
```

Maybe now something goes offline? Thanks!

Comment: Disable instant run

Comment: Thanks! It works!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Please consider making that an answer to the question so that it can be marked as accepted.

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda ok I will do that, fellow panda

Comment: @EpicPandaForce 

Comment: I now have no problem deploying to phones, but still have problem generate signed bundle (to deploy to Google Play)...

Comment: I amended the original question. Please help!

Comment: That seems to be an independent problem, and it just sounds like you should try adding `mavenCentral()` repository to your build gradle `allprojects { repositories {` block, preferably *above* `jcenter()`

Comment: Hi, EpicPandaForce, since I am not familiar with the build system, can you point me to something I can read/understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the messages:

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../instant_run_split_apk_resources
> ```

I'd say, try disabling Instant Run.

Comment: I now get the deployment to phone working, but disabling instant run seems to cause problem for generating signed app (to deploy to Google Play). Amended the original question.